# Hide/Display tabs (and its corresponding content) with check boxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Well, this must be very simple to do for most of you, but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

I have a set of tabs and on top of the tabs is a set of checkboxes ; each checkbox 'corresponds' to a tab.

What I need is to be able to activate/deactivate each checkbox and have its corresponding tab (and the tab's content) hide/display.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="show-results-from">
  <ul>
    <li>See results from:</li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input name="a" type="checkbox" id="a" checked disabled>
        Products &amp; Services <span>(16)</span></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="b" id="b" checked>
        Publications <span>(9)</span></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="c" id="c" checked>
        Other <span>(150)</span></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><span rel="tabs1" class="defaulttab">Products &amp; Services</span></li>
  <li><span rel="tabs2">Publications</span></li>
  <li><span rel="tabs3">Other</span></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs1">content</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs2">content</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs3">content</div>
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I apologize, I should've added the script for my tabs, FYI, I'm not using jQuery UI Tabs:

```
$(function() { 
    $('.tabs span:first-child').click(function(){
        switch_tabs($(this));
        return false;
    }); 
    switch_tabs($('.defaulttab'));
});

function switch_tabs(obj)
{
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $('.tabs span:first-child').removeClass("selected");
    var id = obj.attr("rel");
    $('#'+id).show();
    obj.addClass("selected");
}
```

Script taken from this tutorial:  http://justfreetemplates.com/blog/2009/08/31/ultra-simple-jquery-tabs.html

**More info:**

I didn't really think about the user cases/situations, so here are two:

1. I can't have no tabs, I need to have at least one 'default' tab, so for that I added 'disabled' to the first checkbox thus the first tab can not be hidden. *This one is solved.*
2. What happens is the user hides a tab that's active? Well, my solution, if this happens, would be to make the the default tab, active. **Any idea how to 'restore' the class 'selected' to the default tab if a an already selected tab is hidden?**

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `value` to each checkbox with the id of the tab it should control:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" value="tabs1" />
```

...then you can do this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('div.show-results-from').find(':checkbox').click( function(){
    if( $('ul.tabs li').find('span.selected[rel='+this.value+']').length
        && !this.checked ){
        // if user unchecking the "selected" li/tab
        switch_tabs($('.defaulttab')); // choose default tab
    }
    $('#'+this.value).toggle( this.checked );
    $('ul.tabs li').has('span[rel='+this.value+']').toggle( this.checked ); 
  });
});
```

You might also be interested in the jQuery-UI tabs functionality if you don't want to roll your own.

---

Edit: To address @Ricardo's question in the comments below, I added a conditional to switch to the default tab if the user is unchecking the currently selected tab. Untested.

Comment: Ken, I used your script and it worked great. I added a 'value' to each checkbox and it worked. However, I forgot about the user case where the user decides to hide a tab that's 'selected', thus the user ends up with no active tab. So what I need, if this happens, is to restore the 'selected' class to the first tab. Read my explanation in my question above. Any idea how to go about that? Thanks!

Comment: @Ricardo, I've tried to address your update above. It's all untested, but the idea is to add a conditional that switches to your default tab -- if the tab currently `.selected` has a `rel` matching the `value` of the clicked checkbox **and** the clicked checkbox is now unchecked. That should mean "the user unchecked a box corresponding to the currently selected tab".

Comment: Hey Ken, it worked absolutely as I needed it to :), awesome! Thanks a lot amigo, and thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 2):

I think JQuery UI Tabs would accomplish what you're trying to do.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul .tabs span").hide();
   $("div .tab-content").hide();
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
      switch this.id:
       {
         case "a":
             $("#tab1").toggle();
             $("#tabs1").toggle();
           break;
           //write case b and c
       }
     });});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your markup you can do something like this. [See the live example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/PgCYM/1/).

```
$('.show-results-from input:checkbox').each(function(i, el){
    this.index = i;
}).change(function(){
    var $span = $('ul.tabs li').eq(this.index).find('span');
    if(this.checked)
        $('#' + $span.attr('rel')).show('fast');
    else
        $('#' + $span.attr('rel')).hide('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using jQueryUI tabs (please post a link to how you're creating tabs), you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="a" id="a" class="tab-check" value="tabs1" checked='checked'>
            Products &amp; Services <span>(16)</span></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="b" id="b" class="tab-check" value="tabs2" checked='checked'>
            Publications <span>(9)</span></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="c" id="c" class="tab-check" value="tabs3" checked='checked'>
            Other <span>(150)</span></label>
    </li>
```

**Note:** I've initialized all of your checkboxes to 'checked' and given each checkbox a value corresponding to a tab id.  I've also added a class `tab-check` to each input so I can add an event handler to each checkbox.

Given that HTML, you could write JS like this:

```
$("input.tab-check").change(function() {
    $("a[href='#" + this.value + "']").parent().toggle();
    $("#" + this.value).toggle();
});
```

Which hides/shows the tab and content depending on the state of the checkbox.

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/uy7AG/

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your example, it works very well. However, I'm not using jQuery UI Tabs. Read my comment in my question above, I updated it.

Comment: @Ricardo: Okay, sorry for the confusion.  I'll leave this answer up in case anyone gets here looking for a jQueryUI solution.